# How to speed up the turtle while in a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

I'm trying to make the turtle move faster, which I would normally do using

```
import turtle as t

t.speed(0)
t.tracer(0,0)
```

But when I have it in a canvas using RawTurtle(), I'm not sure how to do this.

```
root = tk.Tk() #create root window

#create turtle canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()
t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.ht()
```

Here's my code. Anyone know how?

Comment: Try `t.speed(0)` and `t.getscreen().tracer(0, 0)`.

Comment: I already tried doing ```t.speed(0)``` and ```t.tracer(0,0)``` which didn't work. when I use ```t.getscreen().tracer(0,0)```, it crashes the program.

Comment: I don't have the issue.  Did you call it after the line `t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)`?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I tried it again just now and there was no error and it didn't crash, but when I do ```t.forward(100)``` or any other turtle command, it doesn't move.

Comment: Since you have disabled `tracer`, you need to call `t.getscreen().update()` to refresh the screen.

Answer (score 1):

First, either do one or the other of these, not both:

```
t.speed(0)
t.tracer(0,0)
```

The `speed(0)` aka `speed('fastest')` gets you the fastest drawing animation.  The `tracer(0)` *eliminates* drawing animation altogether.  They don't add together.

You can get maximum speed, i.e. eliminate drawing animation, in turtle *embedded* in a `Canvas` by using turtle's `TurtleScreen()` wrapper:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = RawTurtle(screen)

turtle.circle(100)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a few edits to your code. For starters, you need to work all the commands after the `t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)` line. Then you need to add a `.mainloop()` function at the end.

This would be your final code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk() #create root window
import turtle
#create turtle canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()
t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.speed(1)
t.forward(100)
t.ht()
root.mainloop()
```

When the speed is set to 1, this is the output: 
[image: Output]

When the speed is set to 0, this is the output: 
[image: Output 2]

Sorry about the gifs, and hope this helps!